# quiknode does not support eth_sign

Tags: go-ethereum

I found that on the web of quiknode it says quiknode do not support eth sign and maybe infura does not also
What should I do ? I want to use ethereum.php so I need to create eth sign and send transaction by php if the api do not support eth sign. Whether this means I need to use some other way to do it such as nodejs

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107249/discussion-on-question-by-louis-quiknode-does-not-support-eth-sign).

Answer (score 2):

According to https://infura.io/docs Infura does not support eth_sign either — probably for the same reason QuikNode doesn’t (security).

The solution is to sign the transaction using your private key and then use eth_sendRawTransaction.

These may shed additional info:

https://medium.com/blockchain-musings/how-to-create-raw-transactions-in-ethereum-part-1-1df91abdba7c

https://twitter.com/QuikNode/status/1035517337187835905

Answer (score 1):

## Ive used ethereum-tx a few times to do this.

#### Get ethereum-tx for php

`composer require web3p/ethereum-tx`

#### Example tx

```
use Web3p\EthereumTx\Transaction;

// without chainId
$transaction = new Transaction([
    'nonce' => '0x01',
    'from' => '0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155',
    'to' => '0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567',
    'gas' => '0x76c0',
    'gasPrice' => '0x9184e72a000',
    'value' => '0x9184e72a',
    'data' => '0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675'
]);

// with chainId
$transaction = new Transaction([
    'nonce' => '0x01',
    'from' => '0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155',
    'to' => '0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567',
    'gas' => '0x76c0',
    'gasPrice' => '0x9184e72a000',
    'value' => '0x9184e72a',
    'chainId' => 1,
    'data' => '0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675'
]);

// hex encoded transaction
$transaction = new Transaction('0xf86c098504a817c800825208943535353535353535353535353535353535353535880de0b6b3a76400008025a028ef61340bd939bc2195fe537567866003e1a15d3c71ff63e1590620aa636276a067cbe9d8997f761aecb703304b3800ccf555c9f3dc64214b297fb1966a3b6d83');
```

#### Example Sign

```
use Web3p\EthereumTx\Transaction;

$signedTransaction = $transaction->sign('your private key');
```

https://github.com/web3p/ethereum-tx